# Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

i have very simple xamarin application , with 2 activities , when i want to start my second activity xamarin in visual studio 2017 show "Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: " ERROR

Comment: have u added these activities in the manifest ?

Comment: In xamarin ? No how should i do ?

Comment: Can you please post the full error in question? You can use the `Continue` button when the `UnhandledException` dialog appears to the point of breaking out of debugging mode and view your `Output` window to see the full stack trace.

Comment: full Error : Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

Comment: Please post your code that how did you open your `second activity` and your second `Activity` code.

Comment: Second activity just show empty layout

Comment: Sorry for late, but I think we'd likely need to see some code to help you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: i have getting same error !!any update ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

(ref.: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android_multiscreen/hello,android_multiscreen_quickstart/)

This work:

```
translationHistoryButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(TranslationHistoryActivity));
    intent.PutStringArrayListExtra("phone_numbers", phoneNumbers);
    StartActivity(intent);
};
```

This get Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException:

```
translationHistoryButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(TranslationHistoryActivity));
    //intent.PutStringArrayListExtra("phone_numbers", phoneNumbers);
    //StartActivity(intent);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Install 'Android Support Repository' 
**Tool->Android->Android SDK manager->Tools->Extras->Android Support Repository**

After installed, Rebuild your project.